# Sorting a file based on Ist column and simultaneously modifing the 2nd column also in the file

Tags: python

In this file i have two columns where Ist column describes the time in float and 2nd column denotes the string.

```
<time> <str>
8.45 A
6.12 B
10.12 C
1.45 D
2.12 E
0.45 F
....
...
..
```

i want to sort the file according to the 1st column and the output should look like this:

```
0.45 F
1.45 D
2.12 E
6.12 B
8.45 A
10.12 C
```

Please help!My approach for solving this was: I was putting each column in two lists each. I was sorting the array with float numbers and simultaneously making the necessary adjustments.

Comment: I don't see the "simultaneously modifying the second column" part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('filename.txt', 'w') as fout:
     for line in sorted(open('filename.txt', 'r').readlines(), key=lambda x:float(x.split()[0])):
         fout.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
li = ['Do you know how to read a file ?',
      'Do you know how to split a string into a list ?',
      'Do you know how to sort a list ?',
      'Do you know how to join string elements of a list ?',
      'Do you know how to write in a file ?']

def your_answer(e):
    y = 'go'
    while y not in ('yes','no'):
        y = raw_input('%s\nenter yes or no :' % e)
    return y

if any(your_answer(e)=='no' for e in li):
    print 'Please, read the documentations.'
else:
    print 'Show what you tried.'
```